# How can I fix this old IP parsing java code

Tags: java

Haven't been in the loop code wise for the last 10 years and want to fix this old program for network management parsing ips

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class ips {
            private static Pattern ex = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}");
            private static Matcher match;
            static Writer output;
            static int loop = 0;
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
                String filen = args[0];
                File file = new File(filen);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
                output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("ips"));
                while(dis.available()!=0){
                String it = dis.readLine();
                match = ex.matcher(it);
                while (match.find() ){
                     System.out.println( match.group() );
                     output.write(match.group()+"\n");
                     loop++;
                }
                }
                output.close();
                System.out.println("Done parsing the Nmap log.\n"+loop+" ips total.");
            }
}
```

Error;

> > javac -Xlint ips.java  ips.java:18: warning: [deprecation] readLine() in DataInputStream has been deprecated
> >                     String it = dis.readLine();
> >                                    ^ 1 warning

I realize it's been depreciated but have a wrist injury and can't use the computer much to debug it :( any tips on how to recode it to use the latest formatting?

Comment: its just a warning, not an error. (Should still compile and run)

Comment: As the message says, it is a warning, not an error. If you want to fix it, read [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine())